# How to change the font size with an input type number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Image showing the desirable outcome]

The image above shows a function for a user to select his or her preferenced font size (it's a website for all ages). However, transferring this to code is easier said than done for me. All I found was that I had to use the following method:

```
<input type="number">
```

Is there anyone who knows how to make such a function work with Javascript or jQuery that adjusts the font size to the selected number?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: `$('body').css('font-size', $('#input_id').val())`

Comment: You could add a function into the input, e.g.: <input type="number" onchange="someFunction(this.value);" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull the `val()` of the input on a submission and set the font size using `.css()`:

**JS**

```
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    var fontSize = $("input[type=number]").val();
    $("p").css({"font-size":fontSize+"px"});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="choose font-size"/>
<input type="submit"/>
<p>Hello</p>
```

[**BUTTON EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpwo5eg1/)

**OR**

You could do it on a `keyup` or `keydown` event (start typing your number):

```
$("input[type=number]").keyup(function(){
    var fontSize = $(this).val();
    $("p").css({"font-size":fontSize+"px"});    
});
```

[**KEYUP EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpwo5eg1/1/)

**OR**

To change the value when clicking the up.down arrows, you can use `.change()`

```
$("input[type=number]").change(function(){
   var fontSize = $(this).val();
   $("p").css({"font-size":fontSize+"px"}); 
});
```

[**CHANGE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tpwo5eg1/2/)

Comment: My answer will not effect if javascript is still disabled. :)

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd read my comment, your answer is not what OP is looking for

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Is it possible however, to change the font size dinamically, meaning that as soon as you hit the up/down button the font adjusts?

Answer (score 0):

**This is the answer for your question**

**CSS**

```
input[type=number] {
font-size: 31px;
}
```

Comment: im boycotting downvoting, so if you get downvoted it wasnt me: but this is not at all correct. OP wants a dynamic way for a user to set the font-size

Comment: this is not going to work when input value is changed.

Comment: How to change the font size with an input type number?  i posted this answer to change font size for input number.which is right.

Comment: you have missed the part `how to make such a function work with Javascript or jQuery that adjusts the font size to the selected number`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 <input type="text" class="inp">

 .inp { font-size:20px; }
```